# Thumbnail upload via YouTube API: Why does it show a surrogate image?

Tags: youtube-api

I am using a small self written Java program which uploads videos and thumbnails to YouTube (I communicate with the API directly not via a special YT-library).

Since roughly last week uploading of thumbnails does not work anymore, although I have not changed anything in my program. The API does not report an error, but when I log in to my YouTube-Account it shows the following image instead of the thumbnail:

[image: the image shown instead of the thumbnail]

This is different from what happens if no thumbnail is uploaded at all, because in this case an automatically chosen snapshot from the video is shown.

Now I can upload my thumbnail using the Web frontend and it works perfectly, which is why I believe it is not a problem with my image.

What could be the cause of the problem?

[This issue](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6591) may or may not be related...

Comment: did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was probably a bug on the server side. Without that I changed anything at all in my application it suddenly continued to work at some point in time (which is already quite a while ago as I forgot about that question here).